# Play Sound AND Swap Image onClick (Menu Bar)

Tags: javascript, html, navigation

EDIT: I found the solution.  Embarrassingly simple.  I removed the following line of code:
        e.preventDefault();

Worked like a charm.  Obviously, I'm quite the noob with js.  I'm off to Code Academy to remedy that. :)

I don't know that my original question was worded very well (I was tired, sorry!) so let me try this another way.

I've been searching for days to solve this, here at SA, other forums, and the mighty Google. So far, no luck.

I have a horizontal menu.  I'd like to make each link play a sound AND swap images onClick.  I've gotten it to play the sound and swap the images, but the anchor link doesn't send you down the page to the appropriate text section.

Removing the js that controls the image swap (located at the bottom of the html) resolves the anchor link problem.  But I need both the sound and image events to occur.

I've only coded the first two links thus far.

Hopefully, this explains my problem better.

Thanks again, all.

Comment: What exactly is the 'issue'? the onclick doesn't work? the page doesn't jump to the appropriate anchor?

Comment: The page doesn't jump to the anchor. Sound works fine.

Comment: Can you provide a demonstration of your problem in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here it is, ddlshack.  Hope this helps!  Remember, only the Home and About links are coded.  http://jsfiddle.net/tBpMV/1/

Comment: Just to add...I realized today that when I removed the last js at the bottom of the body, the anchors work as expected.  Problem is, that is the code that controls the image swap.

Answer (score 0):

The href of your anchor tags are `#`. This won't change/reload the page, it will just change the url fragment. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: I've edited my question for clarification.  I've only worked on the 1st two links so far.  Obviously, I don't expect the others to work.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, removing the following line of code solved the problem.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

I hope this helps someone as green as I am with js from agonizing over something simple, as I did.  Sheesh!